# How to shorten this script to make it fit in GPO GUI?

Tags: file, scripting, windows-installer, transform

Huy Guys

How do you shorten this script to make it fit in a GPO GUI or make a transform file for it? We changed the share name to remove the spaces

Should read like this now. Its critical:

msiexec /i "\ho-dlpendpoint\DLPAgent\32\AgentInstall.msi

msiexec /i "\ho-dlpendpoint\DLP Agent\32\AgentInstall.msi"/q INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Manufacturer\Endpoint Agent\" ENDPOINTSERVER="ho-dlpendpoint.ppsdmn.co.za:8000" KEY="BD075B59564B27304D69C67FA44561363CE94CBB54F3436EC74CF0E62F02382D62C95D7D182258103697520846B25444:43AEB4D39CF0EFD836F49DB518F4B7037C1AF151" UNINSTALLPASSWORDKEY="98B3085301D33FE35B59A038D85CFB0446028522" SERVICENAME="EDPA" WATCHDOGNAME="WDP" ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" /L*v %SystemDrive%\installAgent.log

Below is all the explinations of the different parameters:

msiexec /i "\ho-dlpendpoint\DLP Agent\32\AgentInstall.msi"
this is a fileshare accessable to all users - we donot object to first copying the .msi to the local machine, then executing it there e.g.
msiexec /i c:\AgentInstall.msi
we are open to suggestions, recomendations and best practice here

/q 
quiet install - required

INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Manufacturer\Endpoint Agent\" 
this is that default that Symantec uses - please leave as is for ongoing continuity

ENDPOINTSERVER="ho-dlpendpoint.ppsdmn.co.za:8000" 
this is our endpoint server and the communications port, this cannot be changed

KEY="BD075B59564B27304D69C67FA44561363CE94CBB54F3436EC74CF0E62F02382D62C95D7D182258103697520846B25444:43AEB4D39CF0EFD836F49DB518F4B7037C1AF151" 
the cert, cannot be changed

UNINSTALLPASSWORDKEY="98B3085301D33FE35B59A038D85CFB0446028522" 
our designated uninstall password cert key, this must not be changed

if you would like to test the install/uninstall process do not specify an uninstall password; rather use this for test purposes:
UNINSTALLPASSWORDKEY=""

SERVICENAME="EDPA" 
the default service name, we never change this

WATCHDOGNAME="WDP" 
the watchdog for the EDPA service to detect tampering with the EDPA service, we never change this

ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" 
we use this do the agent does not appear in the remove program files - we never change this

/L*v %SystemDrive%\installAgent.log
we write the install process to this log file for problem determination

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of things in there that never change, so it's not clear from your question why you can't:

1. Put them in the MSI file permanently. For example ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT and maybe some others.
2. Make a transform. I'm not sure why you're asking how because that should be out there for you to find out, but basically you'd make a copy of that MSI file and use something like Orca to add most of those items to the Property table, as many as necessary. Then use Orca's Transform->Generate transform to get your .mst file, then use that .mst file in the command line instead of the property list.